# Number of days for a given year inside a date range

Tags: c#, date, math, range, date-range

Say I have an year, 2017.

I then have a date range, `01/07/2017` - `01-07-2018`  *OR* `01/07/2017` - `01-01-2017` *OR* `01/01/2016` - `01/01/2018` ( <- this should return 365 days)

I now need to calculate how many `total days` are there in the given `range` for the given `year`.

Note that dates are stored as dd/mm/yyyy with an always 00:00:00 time.

What would the best logic be considering all possible cases of ranges?

Comment: 1. Get the number of days between both ends
2. If first date starts before that year subtract the difference.
3. If the second date is after that year subtract the difference

Comment: Be sure to consider February 29 in your test cases.

Comment: I don't really understand what do you mean by: "01/01/2016 - 01/01/2018 ( <- this should return 365 days)"

Comment: Isn't there a gap of 2 years ? Do you need days in total for 2016 and 2017 or only for one year?

Comment: There's an *implicit* range given by the number 2017 at the start of the question and meant to cover all days in that year. There's an *explicit* range coming from elsewhere, the examples of which are in the second paragraph. We need to compute the *overlap* between these ranges and find out how long *that* is. The answer can never be greater than 366 since one of the ranges is for a single year.

Comment: Ok, in this case i misunderstood the question...  my answer doesn't really do what was the requirement.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever 366 is only for bissextile years

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can compute the start and end dates for a year easily:

```
var start2017 = new DateTime(2017,1,1);
var end2017 = new DateTime(2017,12,31);
```

And then you can compute the *overlap* between this new range and your other range<sup>1</sup>:

```
var startOverlap = start2017 < startOtherRange ? startOtherRange : start2017;
var endOverlap = end2017 >  endOtherRange ? endOtherRange : end2017;

var totalDays = (endOverlap - startOverlap).TotalDays + 1;
```

The above is correct if ranges are meant to *include* both their start and end dates. If you want, say, an exclusive endpoint then we'd adjust the end of out 2017 computed range one day further forwards and would no longer require the `+1` adjustment at the end)

(And I presume you can derive from there how to turn it into a function if required that takes `year, startRange, endRange` parameters and does the above with some appropriate renaming)

---

<sup>1</sup>I had some vague recollection of `DateTime.Min(value1, value2)` and similarly for `Max` but it's definitely not in the BCL that I can see. Those would replace the conditional operators on the following lines. Once C# has "extension everything" these functions could be written as static extensions to `DateTime`.

Comment: That's the wrong end date.  You actually want `new DateTime(2018,1,1);` otherwise you get 364 days instead of 365 because the time is the beginning of the last day instead of the end.

Comment: @juharr That was always a doubt I had. Can somebody confirm this?

Comment: @juharr - before making that adjustment, we would need to know whether they consider the start and end of ranges to be inclusive or exclusive. The correct correction may just be `+1` on the final result.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever If the end date is after the last day of the year I'd expect they want to include the entire day.

Comment: @k1dev - does your example range, say `01/07/2017 - 01-07-2018` include both 1st July 2017 and 1st July 2017, only one of them, or neither (as well as all other days between). We need to know what the endpoints mean.

Comment: @k1dev We also need to know if your dates include time or if they are truncated

Comment: Dates are time-truncated. If I say 01/07/2017, it starts from 00:00

Comment: @juharr - but if the "other range" that we're working with has an end date of 31st December 2017, we need to know whether that day in included, and that requires us to know what range definition they're working with.

Comment: @k1dev What about the end date.  Do you want to count the last day because technically if you have the time truncated the range ends at the beginning of that day and you'd have to add 1 to make this work.

Comment: @juharr - I've updated my answer to at least be correct for one interpretation (both start and end date are inclusive) and notes on how to adjust appropriately for a common inclusive start/exclusive end pattern.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever well I am expecting that if I have for example a payment to do, and it must be split into two years competence, say 1 month is december and 1 month is january of the year n+1, I must get a 50:50 proportion of the payment, so the total days outputted from the above function you supplied must always be exact in terms of days, in order to be putted in proportion to 365 days of the year

Comment: @k1dev - but again, we need to know *what your ranges mean to you*, as I already asked above. Is the range `01/07/2017 - 01/07/2018` the 365 days that started with `01/07/2017` and *ends before* `01/07/2018` or the 366 days that ends at the end of `01/07/2018`. That's what we're trying to eke out from you.

Comment: yes, 01/07/2017 - 01/07/2018 must return 365 absolutely

Comment: Then your ranges have an *inclusive* start point and an *exclusive* end point - they don't include the actual day you're specifying as the end date. Which means you need the adjustments I describe in the paragraph below the code.